# mysql реализовать запрос с помощью JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Есть 2 таблицы names, actions:

```
name_id | name
   1   |  Bob
   2   |  Rob

action_id | name_1_id | name_2_id
    1     |     1     |     2
```

Выбираю данные так:

```
SELECT action_id, 
       (SELECT name FROM names WHERE name_id = name_1_id),
       (SELECT name FROM names WHERE name_id = name_2_id) 
FROM actions 
WHERE action_id = 1
```

результат запроса:

```
1 | Bob | Rob
```

Как реализовать такой запрос с помощью JOIN, что-то не получается, уже кучу вариантов перепробовал...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Секрет тут только один - дать алиасы таблицам. И тогда одну таблицу можно джойнить несколько раз.

```
SELECT action_id, n1.nme, n2.name
FROM actions 
    join names n1 on n1.name_id = name_1_id
    join names n2 on n2.name_id = name_2_id
WHERE action_id = 1`
```